# Reading value from text field of form_for in rails 3, params[:x] not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, textfield, parameters, form-for

I have sign up form in Rails 3.2.9 . It contains a text field for login name called 'login' in a form-for ,I want to use the value in that field to check in database for duplicates for check login name availability function . But the params[:login] is not reading the values properly from the form!! is anything wrong woth form_for?? or how can we make the controller read the values?

### signup.html.erb

```
<%= form_for :user do |f| -%>
<span class='error'><%= flash[:msg] %></span>

<p><label for="login"><span class='redcolor'>*</span>Login</label><br/>
<%= f.text_field :login  %></p>

<p><%= submit_tag 'Check Login Availability', :name => 'check' %></p>

<p><label for="email"><span class='redcolor'>*</span>Email</label><br/>
<%= f.text_field :email %></p>

<p><label for="password"><span class='redcolor'>*</span>Password</label><br/>
<%= f.password_field :password %></p>

<p><label for="password_confirmation"><span class='redcolor'>*</span>Confirm Password</label><br/>
<%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></p>

<p><label for="company"><span class='redcolor'>*</span>Company</label><br/>
<%= f.text_field :company %></p>

<p><%= submit_tag 'Sign up', :name=> 'sign_up' %></p>
```

the code where i read the value goes like this

### account_controller.rb

```
if params[:check]
  puts "in check"
  username = params[:login]
  puts username//is giving blank
  user = User.find_by_login(username)

  if user
    flash[:msg] = "Sorry Not Available!"
  else
    flash[:msg] = "Available"
  end
```

Here `puts username` is giving blank and hence always 'available' is displayed. When i add name param to login in html page lik this `<%= f.text_field :login,:name => 'login'%>` the code works fine for check availability function but signup function fails due to some DB error saying 'login cant be null'.

Can anybody tell me how to make sure tat params[:login] reads the value properly???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to get the value from `<%= f.text_field :login  %></p>`, that will not be in  `params[:login]`.  If you look at the html generated by that helper, you'll see that the name attribute of the tag is not `login` but is most probably `user[login]`.

Try using `params[:user][:login]`

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using submit_tag in form_for!!!

Change

`<%= submit_tag 'Sign up', :name=> 'sign_up' %>`

to

```
<%= f.submit 'Sign up' %>
```

You are using form_for. So you have to take parameters like `params[:model_name][:field_name]` to get value.

In your case `params[:user][:login]`